# How to handle Undefined or Empty filterQuery in Firebase Query

Tags: firebase

I have a query where initially `filterQuery.searchInput` is undefined. However, when I type something into the search bar it takes on a value. But Firebase doesn’t return anything in this case.
How can I change the query so that if `filterQuery.searchInput` is undefined or an empty string, it returns all documents, and when it has a value, it returns only the matching documents?

```
async fetch(_ctx, filterQuery) {
    const dbQuery = query(cardsCollectionRef, limit(10), where("value", "==", filterQuery.searchInput));
    const snapshot = await getDocs(dbQuery);
    const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
    return data;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with two queries in an if statement

```
async function fetch(_ctx, filterQuery) {
  console.log("fetch", filterQuery);

  let dbQuery;
  if (filterQuery) {
    dbQuery = query(cardsCollectionRef, limit(5), where("value", "==", filterQuery));
  } else {
    dbQuery = query(cardsCollectionRef, limit(5));
  }

  const snapshot = await getDocs(dbQuery);
  const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
  return data;
}
```